# list of non-repeating values from a tuple list of values terminate on a repeat value

Tags: python, list, tuples

tuple list p looks as follows :
p=[(0, 2), (2, 6), (6, 7), (7, 3), (3, 7), (7, 6), (6, 4), (4, 5), (5, 4), (4, 1), (1, 4), (4, 6), (6, 2)]

How to return only the values which occur once and then break out of the loop if there is a repeat?
For example, here we return `list= 0,2,6,7,3`.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should provide what have you tried, where did you stuck etc.

Comment: It's not clear what you really want. Try and explain that better. Also, add your code - what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your required output is the list `[0, 2, 6, 7, 3]`, then you could use the following approach:

```
p = [(0, 2), (2, 6), (6, 7), (7, 3), (3, 7), (7, 6), (6, 4), (4, 5), (5, 4), (4, 1), (1, 4), (4, 6), (6, 2)]
present = {}
output = []

for x in p:
    output.append(x[0])

    if frozenset(x) in present:
        break
    else:
        present[frozenset(x)] = 0

print output
```

This uses Python's `frozenset` as a dictionary key to determine if your pair of numbers has already been seen, and break out of a loop.

It will display the following:

```
[0, 2, 6, 7, 3]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you mean how to make it a function?

Answer (score 1):

''' 
If your required output is the list [0, 2, 6, 7, 3], then you could use the following approach: '''

```
p = [(0, 2), (2, 6), (6, 7), (7, 3), (3, 7), (7, 6), (6, 4), (4, 5), (5, 4), 
    (4, 1), (1, 4), (4, 6), (6, 2)]
out_data = []
for i in p:
    if i[0] not in out_data:
        out_data.append(i[0])
    else:
        break
print(out_data)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.